# Is the completeness of the codomain necessary?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces

I am studying Functional Analysis from Joseph Muscat's book. This is given as an exercise in his book:

Show that a continuous function $f: X \to Y$ with $X,Y$ complete metric spaces, maps totally bounded subsets to totally bounded subsets of $Y$.

Here's my attempt:

Let $B\subseteq X$ be totally bounded. Let $\{ f(x_n) \}$ be a sequence in $f(B)$. Since $B$ is totally bounded, there is a Cauchy subsequence $\{ x_{n_k}\}$ of $\{ x_n \}$. Since $X$ is complete, $\{ x_{n_k} \}$ converges to some $x\in X$. Then $\{ f(x_{n_{k}}) \}$ converges to $f(x)$. Hence $\{ f(x_{n_k}) \}$ is Cauchy. Thus, $f(B)$ is totally bounded.

We didn't use the completeness of $Y$. Is this proof okay?

Comment: Looks good to me. Also, it's enough to consider restriction of $f$ to $\overline{B}$, which is compact, and continuous image of compact is compact (thus complete) anyway.